# Is there a way to use Bosh to handle an app deployed on a local cluster without an IaaS?

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh, bosh-deployer

I have a cluster of local machines, and I would like to deploy a web app on it using Bosh. However, [the Bosh documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/index.html) appears to show a lack of options if you do not use a popular IaaS.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3):

The "Install Bosh" section of the [Bosh Docs](https://bosh.io/docs) (you're looking at the Cloud Foundry docs) has a more complete list of supported IaaS technologies (each IaaS technology has its own CPI, which is the specific code for interacting with that IaaS).

You mentioned deploying to a "cluster of local machines".  I don't know what that is exactly, but if you're looking to deploy to bare metal you're probably looking for the [RackHD CPI](https://bosh.io/docs/rackhd-cpi.html).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

BOSH requires additional package called CPI in order to run on different platforms. You can check [Github](https://github.com/search?langOverride=&q=bosh%20cpi&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories) for available third-party CPIs.